# Cron BAD FILE MODE vs permission denied

Tags: unix, cron, centos

I have a `cron` job for backuping my databases:

```
➜  ~ crontab -l
@daily /etc/cron.d/pg_backup.sh
```

There is a problem with setting appropriate permissions, though.

When I have:

```
➜  ~ ls -l /etc/cron.d/pg_backup.sh
-rwxr-xr--. 1 root root 1359 Apr 14 21:39 /etc/cron.d/pg_backup.sh
```

and then check `grep "pg_backup.sh" /var/log/cron`, I see:

```
localhost crond[11881]: (root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/pg_backup.sh)
```

However, when I modify `pg_backup.sh` as:

```
chmod 644 pg_backup.sh
```

It disables the warning:

```
localhost CROND[11064]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.d/pg_backup.sh)
```

but I see

```
➜  ~ cat /var/mail/root
# ...
/bin/sh: /etc/cron.d/pg_backup.sh: Permission denied
```

What are the appropriate file permissions then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you've installed the script to be executed in the `/etc/cron.d` directory.  That directory is for crontab files, not shell commands. (Take a look at the existing files in that directory.)

There's a check in `crond` that any files in that directory are not readable or writable by anyone other than the owner (which must be `root`), and are not executable by anyone.  So you'd have to change the permissions to `600`, or to something even stricter, to avoid the message -- and then, as you've seen, you wouldn't be able to execute the script.

Instead, put the script somewhere else and update your crontab:

```
@daily /some/other/directory/pg_backup.sh
```