# (root) BAD FILE MODE (/var/spool/cron/root) in AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron

My cron job is working fine. The root file contains the url of the file to be triggered.

To modify the root file, I had changed the permission to 777 and then downloaded the file. I had uploaded the modified file but the cron job is stops working now.

It is throwing error as **BAD FILE MODE**. I had changed permission to the default one i.e 700 but not getting done.

Suggest me ideas or link to get things done. I had tried a lot of things but haven't got any right. Out of ideas now. Any kind help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the mode be 600, not 700?

Comment: before changing the permission for first time, it is 700

Comment: change permission to 600 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634759/cron-bad-file-mode-vs-permission-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your line endings are on Windows instead of Unix. Try editing the file line endings with your IDE/Editor. Or create a new file, make sure the line endings are Unix and re-upload.

Comment: but i don't know what makes the file run. Actually yesterday i changed the file with new file and also made the permission change to 644. thanks again

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer :) ! Glad I could help.

Comment: @SinghKunal It has everything to do with the file line endings. Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n"). You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are translated properly.